# Django 1.8.4 with REST Framework select opposite column based on request.user in contacts table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am not quite sure how to proceed on this and look for an answer that keeps performance on top.

I have the following **model**:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    STATUS_VERIFIED = 'verified'
    STATUS_PENDING = 'pending'
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_VERIFIED, STATUS_VERIFIED),
        (STATUS_PENDING, STATUS_PENDING),
    )

    FAVOURITE_A = 'fava'
    FAVOURITE_B = 'favb'
    FAVOURITE_NONE = 'none'
    FAVOURITE_BOTH = 'AndB'

    FAVOURITE_CHOICES = (
        (FAVOURITE_A, FAVOURITE_A),
        (FAVOURITE_B, FAVOURITE_B),
        (FAVOURITE_NONE, FAVOURITE_NONE),
        (FAVOURITE_BOTH, FAVOURITE_BOTH),
    )
    source = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name="source_user")
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name="destination_user")

    status = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    favourite = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=FAVOURITE_CHOICES)
```

The following **serializer**:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    source_uuid = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_field_source_uuid')
    source_email = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_field_source_email')
    source_first_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_field_source_first_name')
    source_last_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_field_source_last_name')

    destination_uuid = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_field_destination_uuid')
    destination_email = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_field_destination_email')
    destination_first_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_field_destination_first_name')
    destination_last_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_field_destination_last_name')

    def get_field_source_uuid(self, obj):
        return obj.source.uuid

    def get_field_source_email(self, obj):
        return obj.source.email

    def get_field_source_first_name(self, obj):
        return obj.source.first_name

    def get_field_source_last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.source.last_name

    def get_field_destination_uuid(self, obj):
        return obj.destination.uuid

    def get_field_destination_email(self, obj):
        return obj.destination.email

    def get_field_destination_first_name(self, obj):
        return obj.destination.first_name

    def get_field_destination_last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.destination.last_name

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = (
            'source_uuid',
            'source_email',
            'source_first_name',
            'source_last_name',
            'destination_uuid',
            'destination_email',
            'destination_first_name',
            'destination_last_name',
        )
```

And this is the related **view**:

```
class Addressbook(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            addressbook = Contact.objects.filter(Q(source=request.user) or Q(destination=request.user), status=Contact.STATUS_VERIFIED)
            serializer = ContactSerializer(addressbook, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            content = {'status': 1}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

**What is this:**
I have an API which allows a user to add a contact. There are two users. Lets call them `source` and `destination`, as seen in the model. Whether they are "contacts" or not is defined by their status: `Pending` or `Verified`. A user can check for pending contact requests, as well as accept such request. These are not provided, as they are working fine.

A user can retrieve their addressbook. **The addressbook should return a list of contacts that are verified.** Which means, that the user should not appear in said addressbook.

**What is the problem**:
How can I tell the serializer to either use `source` or `destination` to add the contact to the returning data, depending on whichever the logged in user is.

So when `source = request.user` and `destination` is the verified contact it should only `return destination`. When the `destination=request.user` it should only `return source` in the seralized data. This should obviously work for `many=True`, therefore at the same time.

**The question**
Is this possible via OUTER JOINS within the filter statement? Or would I need to work with the serializer in python, which I would probably like to avoid to keep the code as simple as possible and reusable.

Comment: Have you looked at [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) ?

Comment: Well, select_related is not a problem, I haven't taken care of that yet though. But I think it would not help me in this case with the actual problem, as I care more about the column within the same row I am selecting.

Answer (score 0):

In your serializer method, you can access to `request user`

```
def get_field_emails(self,obj):
    request = self.context.get('request')
    user = request.user
    #Here you check you user type
    if your_user_is_destination:
        return destination.email
    else:
        return source.email
```